# Rsync Files only if they have not been changed in the last 2 minutes

Tags: rsync, file-transfer

I'm trying to write a simple cronjob that looks in a specific directory, performs a find command to determine if a file has been modified in the last two minutes, and if not, transfer that file to another directory.

I can find the files that need moving without any issues and rsync those files, but when I merge both commands, all files get moved even if they've been changed in the previous 2minutes.

So far, I've tried:

```
find /tmp/dir/* -cmin +2 | rsync -ogr --chown=user:group --remove-source-files --exclude=".*" /tmp/dir/* /tmp/dir2
```

As well as:

```
find /tmp/dir/* -cmin +2 -exec rsync -ogr --chown=user:group --remove-source-files --exclude=".*" {} /tmp/dir2 \;
```

I'm not sure what's going on, and why the find command which returns the proper files can't be piped or "exec-ed" properly into the rsync command.

Cheers in advance,

IknowImBad

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to rsync files / folders from a specific date forward?](https://serverfault.com/questions/538767/how-to-rsync-files-folders-from-a-specific-date-forward)

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use a pipe, you have to tell rsync to read the source files from stdin: **-include-from=-**

I will be better to not use the asterisk character in find and rsync.

The *--exclude="." should not be needed.

```
find /tmp/dir/ -cmin +2 |
rsync -ogr --chown=user:group --remove-source-files --include-from=- /tmp/dir/ /tmp/dir2/
```